# WSL 2 install on windows 10 Enterprise

Tags: windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl2

I am trying to install WSL 2 on my windows 10 Enterprise x64 laptop. I think I have all the necessary updates and I am following this page:
[MSFT documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10).

However, I am seeing the following error at step 5 in the above page

```
wsl --set-default-version 2
Access is denied.
PS C:\Users\123456> wsl --set-default-version 2
Access is denied.


systeminfo | find "System Type"
System Type:               x64-based PC
```

[image]

I have the above OS build. Any help is appreciated

Comment: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/WSL/issues/809 and https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/kb4565503-installed-then-wsl-2-failed-to-start/25794c4f-0b20-465e-bbdb-a8af3d9e0e88

Comment: If you are running PowerShell in elevated mode, try running it as non-elevated (or vice-versa).